# ng update not running migration.json schematic

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-upgrade, angular-schematics

#### Versions

node --version
v8.11.3

npm --version
6.4.1

```
ng --version
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.1.1
Node: 8.11.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... common, core, router

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular       0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack       0.7.5
@angular-devkit/core                0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics          0.7.1
@angular/animations                 6.1.0
@angular/cdk                        6.4.7
@angular/cli                        6.1.1
@angular/compiler                   6.1.0
@angular/compiler-cli               6.1.0
@angular/forms                      6.1.0
@angular/http                       6.1.0
@angular/language-service           6.1.0
@angular/platform-browser           6.1.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   6.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                    6.1.5
@schematics/angular                 0.7.1
@schematics/update                  0.7.1
rxjs                                6.3.3
typescript                          2.9.2
webpack                             4.9.2
```

#### Repro steps

I have a private project so I am unable to share the repo, so sorry in advance. I have an angular project to which I have added schematics support so I can update it using `ng update`. So I have a schematics folder with a `migration.json` file :

```
{
  "$schema": "../../../node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/collection-schema.json",
  "schematics": {
    "migration01": {
      "version": "1.0.0-nav-menu-with-migration.3",
      "description": "Update",
      "factory": "./src/ng-update/index"
    }
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.schematics.json` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/files/*.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.schematics.spec.json` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
    ],
    "declaration": false
  },
  "include": [
    "./spec/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

`jasmine.json` :

```
{
  "spec_dir": "projects/nav-menu/schematics/spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*.spec.js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "projects/nav-menu/schematics/spec/helpers/**/*.js"
  ],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": false
}
```

I have an `ng-update` folder with `index.ts` :

```
import { Rule, SchematicContext, SchematicsException, Tree } from "@angular-devkit/schematics";

export default function(): Rule {
  return (tree: Tree, context: SchematicContext) => {
    context.logger.warn("it's happening!");

    const pkgPath = "/package.json";
    const buffer = tree.read(pkgPath);
    if (buffer == null) {
      throw new SchematicsException("Could not read package.json");
    }
    const content = buffer.toString();
    const pkg = JSON.parse(content);

    if (pkg === null || typeof pkg !== "object" || Array.isArray(pkg)) {
      throw new SchematicsException("Error reading package.json");
    }

    if (!pkg.dependencies) {
      pkg.dependencies = {};
    }

    if (pkg.dependencies["@solarwinds/nav-menu-with-migration"]) {
      pkg.dependencies["ngx-perfect-scrollbar"] = `^7.0.0`;
      pkg.dependencies["ngx-device-detector"] = null;

      tree.overwrite(pkgPath, JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2));
    }

    return tree;
  };
}
```

`package.json` for my nav menu project :

```
{
  "name": "@solarwinds/nav-menu-with-migration",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "css-element-queries": "~0.4.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^7.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.7",
    "@solarwinds/nova-xui": "6.3.0-alpha.10.1322",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "schematics": "./schematics/collection.json",
  "ng-update": {
    "migrations": "./schematics/migration.json"
  }
}
```

Once I publish my package I try to update `nav-menu` in one of my other application's which use this package. I have tried a number of different commands and non of them seem to run the `migration.json` schematic on `ng update`. So I have tried :

`ng update @solarwinds/nav-menu-with-migration --to=1.0.0-nav-menu-with-migration.3 --migrate-only`

and I get the following error: `Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above`

```
Package "@solarwinds/nova-xui" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/cdk" (requires "6.3.3", would install "6.4.7").
                  Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "6.1.0" (extended), wouldinstall "6.1.10").
                  Package "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "6.1.0" (extended), would install "6.1.10").
                  Package "@angular/router" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "6.1.10", would install "6.1.0")
                  Package "@solarwinds/nova-xui" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/router" (requires "6.1.4" (extended), would install "6.1.10").
                  Package "@solarwinds/nova-xui" has an incompatible peer dependency to "rxjs" (requires "6.2.2", would install "6.3.3").
Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above.
```

So I tried with `--force` flag and I do get my `package.json` file updated but I never see my `migration.json` schematic run.

`g update @solarwinds/nav-menu-with-migration --to=1.0.0-nav-menu-with-migration.3 --force --migrate-only`

```
Package "@solarwinds/nova-xui" has an incompatible peer dependency to "rxjs" (requires "6.2.2", would install "6.3.3").
                  Package "@solarwinds/nova-xui" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/cdk" (requires "6.3.3", would install "6.4.7").
                  Package "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "6.1.0" (extended), would install "6.1.10").
                  Package "@angular/router" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "6.1.10", would install "6.1.0")
                  Package "@solarwinds/nova-xui" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/router" (requires "6.1.4" (extended), would install "6.1.10").
                  Package "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "6.1.0" (extended), would install "6.1.10").
    Updating package.json with dependency rxjs @ "6.3.3" (was "6.2.2")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/cdk @ "6.4.7" (was "6.4.3")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/core @ "6.1.10" (was "6.1.0")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/router @ "6.1.10" (was "6.1.0")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/common @ "6.1.10" (was "6.1.0")...
```

I am not sure why my `ng update` command is not run. I wanted to test my `migration.json` schematic so I pointed my `collection.json` to point to `ng-update/index` so that when I run `ng add @solarwinds/nav-menu-with-migration@1.0.0-nav-menu-with-migration.3` I can see if my `ng-update` code work and it does work as expected (Note: this was only to test purpose and I do not intend to use `ng add` to run migrations). Here is the output  :

```
TREHMAN-MB:web-application-seed tanzeel.rehman$ ng add @solarwinds/nav-menu-with-migration@1.0.0-nav-menu-with-migration.3Installing packages for tooling via npm.
npm WARN @solarwinds/nav-menu@2.2.0 requires a peer of @solarwinds/nova-xui@6.3.0-alpha.10.1322 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @solarwinds/nova-xui@6.3.0-alpha.12.1825 requires a peer of @angular/animations@6.1.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @solarwinds/nova-xui@6.3.0-alpha.12.1825 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@6.3.3 but none is installed. You must install peerdependencies yourself.
npm WARN @solarwinds/nova-xui@6.3.0-alpha.12.1825 requires a peer of @angular/common@6.1.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @solarwinds/nova-xui@6.3.0-alpha.12.1825 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@6.1.4 but none is installed. You must installpeer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @solarwinds/nova-xui@6.3.0-alpha.12.1825 requires a peer of @angular/core@6.1.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @solarwinds/nova-xui@6.3.0-alpha.12.1825 requires a peer of @angular/forms@6.1.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @solarwinds/nova-xui@6.3.0-alpha.12.1825 requires a peer of @angular/http@6.1.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @solarwinds/nova-xui@6.3.0-alpha.12.1825 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@6.1.4 but none is installed. You mustinstall peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @solarwinds/nova-xui@6.3.0-alpha.12.1825 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@6.1.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @solarwinds/nova-xui@6.3.0-alpha.12.1825 requires a peer of @angular/router@6.1.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsickle@0.30.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @solarwinds/nav-menu-with-migration@1.0.0-nav-menu-with-migration.3 requires a peer of ngx-perfect-scrollbar@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @solarwinds/nav-menu-with-migration@1.0.0-nav-menu-with-migration.3 requires a peer of @solarwinds/nova-xui@6.3.0-alpha.10.1322 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ @solarwinds/nav-menu-with-migration@1.0.0-nav-menu-with-migration.3
updated 1 package and audited 40530 packages in 16.964s
found 10 vulnerabilities (3 low, 5 moderate, 2 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
    it's happening!
UPDATE package.json (4250 bytes)
```

Can someone help me with `ng update` here. Please, Thank you in advance!!

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13139